# Update ArcGIS Online with FME

Tags: fme-form, arcgis-online, feature-service

I am having problems trying to write ArcGIS Online Feature Service in update mode.

Our process is very simple. We published data from Oracle SDE to ArcGIS Online Feature Service with ArcMap. The source is in Place State projection, we set the data frame to WGS84-EPSG 4326 before publishing the service to AGO. We need FME to be able to update the existing AGO Feature Service when a change occurs in the corresponding SDE source layer (records number change). We want to keep the process simple for now, all I need is to write the existing Feature Service with the update and keep the WGS84.

I tried in two ways:

1. Read the SDE layer - Write existing Feature Service in ArcGIS Online (writer mode: insert)
2. Read both SDE feature and his corresponding Feature Service, use a FeatureMerger Transformer to check for updates and write the existing Feature Service in update mode (attached)

..but it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: what is the exact error?

Comment: I am trying now a very simple workbench: SDE Reader to existing Feature Service AGO, which I select from the list. I got : "ArcGIS Online Feature Service Writer: Could not find a layer matching feature type 'CityLimits' "

Comment: What version of FME are you using? I had a similar issue that I'm told is fixed in 2015.1.

Comment: I am using FME Desktop 2015.0

Comment: Try 2015.1, maybe it will work for you. If not, email support@safe.com and provide them a minimal workspace that reproduces the issue and they should be able to help you out.

Comment: Other problem is that, when I am inserting a new Feature Service to AGO, I am not able to set the output coordinate system to WGS84 (4326). I used Reprojector and ESRI Reprojector, from State Plane (2272) to 4326. I get 102100 in the Feature Service definition, which is Web Mercator

Comment: My update works now, but first I must enable the editing mode in ArcGIS Online, otherwise the Feature Service will not support writer mode: Insert. I set the writer to INSERT and TRUNCATE. Truncating is accomplished via a deletion call to the server. It perfectly works for small and medium files, but NOT for big ones. I get a "Python Exception HTTPError: 500 Server Error"